# how can i clone a psycopg2 connection

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

i have an existing psycopg2 connection. i did not create it--it was passed to me.  however, i want to make another connection for a worker thread with the exact config as the one passed to me.  i do not want to share the same connection, which i read otherwise serializes queries.

i did browse http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html, which no immediate answer in sight.

any pythonic hot tips?

thx

Comment: clone a connection ?

Comment: You could pass all the connection information into your worker thread and have it setup it's own connection instead of trying to clone an existing one. Looks like you can extract the connection information by using get_dsn_parameters() 

See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.get_dsn_parameters for more details.

Comment: nice. even .dsn works.  it seems both options strip the password from the connection params though. :/